How many non-overlapping, mutually non-antipodal unit spheres can be placed on the surface of four dimensional unit sphere?
If by linear or semi-definite programming this number could be shown to be less than 24, then this could be a route to showing that the 24-cell (consisting of 12 antipodal pairs of spheres) is the unique kissing configuration in four dimensions.

What do you mean by "placed on the surface". In a touching configuration?

Yes. Is the kissing number for mutually non-antipodal unit spheres in four dimensions less than 24?
